# Save/open OLE object from .mdb in vb winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I am trying to add a feature to my vb winform program where a user can attach files (.doc, .docx, .jpg, .pdf) to a mdb file that holds other text data. The binary file and the file name are stored in the DB.  The file name with path is passed as variable 'fpath'. below is what I have thus far (It is now working, meaning it saves the file name and binary data). Now, how can the user open the saved file? And, if it is a .doc or PDF etc, how do I make the default associated program open it? . Can someone help me with the rest?

Here is the code to store the OLE object:

```
 Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)        Handles btnClear.Click
    'data connection
    Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source=" & _
                           Application.StartupPath & "\data.mdb"
    cn.Open()

    'file name without path
    Dim flName As String = filename.Text 

    'open file from the disk (file path is the path to the file to be opened)
    Using fileStream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(fpath)
        'create new MemoryStream object
        Dim memStream As New MemoryStream()
        memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length)
        'read file to MemoryStream
        fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, CInt(Fix(fileStream.Length)))
        Dim strImage As String = "?"

        Dim arr As Byte()
        arr = memStream.GetBuffer
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblstudent(name, photo) VALUES( ?, ?)"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.Char).Value = flName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@photo", OleDb.OleDbType.Binary).Value = arr

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Data save successfully!")
        cn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `MsgBox` comes too early, it should come after the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and a Try/Catch should be used here. I think you will have to store the file name as well.

Comment: I added the try/catch and switched the order of the msg box. The code doesn't save anything to the db, but it doesn't throw an exception now. not sure what else to do

Comment: Your code and question text don't match. The text says "the user will click a button to browse to the file, and the file name and path are displayed in lable1", but the code doesn't try to save the file name and path (it reads the file into nothing with `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(flName)` that doesn't use the stream you create at all, and then tries to store the uninitialized, non-existant content of that stream into the DB). What are you're trying to do? Save the file name and path? Save the binary content of the file? Please edit to clarify what it is you're asking us for help with here.

Comment: I'd also point out that storing arbitrary binary files inside an mdb s=is not a good plan - after a couple of hundred documents,the mdb will be immense and all your database operations will get slower and slower as there's more disk churn. Store the file in a directory and store the path to it in the mdb...

Comment: Thank you, I edited the above. I am not sure how to read the path into the memory string. the path is the string, flName. I didn't know how to get the file into the memory string. Yes, I want o save the content of the file to the db so that users could retrieve the document(s) at a later date.

Comment: The above should read: not sure how to read path into memory stream. trying to work with `arrImage = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(flName)` but not having luck. I am working on storing the file name with the file, but the file is the important part. Obviously I am a hobbiest with programing.

Comment: @ Basic , thanks for the tip. The database would have only a few files in total. The user just attaches a word doc, a pdf and maybe a picture. The rest of the database is is a table with about a max 10 rows of text data. I wanted to store it all as one file so that is can be easily uploaded to an ftp (I have that part working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two weeks of searching and trying a bunch of methods, I got it to work. The code above is corrected and working for uploading a file to a .mdb file. The code below will retrieve it. Yes, I know saving files to a mdb is not the best, but there will only be a couple docs or pdf, and I need it all in one file for easy sharing between users.

```
  Private Builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With _
  { _
      .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath & "\data.mdb"), _
      .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0" _
  }

Private Sub btnGetfile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetfile.Click
    Dim selfile As String = fileDgv.CurrentCell.Value.ToString

    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand With _
        { _
            .Connection = cn, _
            .CommandText = "SELECT photo FROM tblstudent WHERE name='" & selfile & "'" _
        }
    Dim NoDataList As New List(Of String)


    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = Nothing
    Dim FileStream As System.IO.FileStream
    Dim Reader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim Data() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim Writer As System.IO.BinaryWriter = Nothing
    Dim bufferSize As Integer = 1000
    Dim buffer(bufferSize - 1) As Byte
    Dim startIndex As Long = 0
    Dim numberOfBytes As Long = 0
    cn.Open()
    Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)
    Reader.Read()
    FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(
        IO.Path.Combine("C:\temp3", "temp", selfile),
        System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
    Writer = New System.IO.BinaryWriter(FileStream)
    Do
        numberOfBytes = Reader.GetBytes(0, startIndex, buffer, 0, bufferSize)
        If numberOfBytes = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        Writer.Write(buffer, 0, CInt(Fix(numberOfBytes)))
        startIndex += numberOfBytes
    Loop While True
    Writer.Flush()
    If Writer IsNot Nothing Then
        Writer.Close()
    End If
    If FileStream IsNot Nothing Then
        FileStream.Close()
    End If
    If Reader IsNot Nothing Then
        Reader.Close()
    End If
    cn.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Done")

End Sub
```